# Sessions in CakePHP, values disapear after error

Tags: php, session, cakephp

Hello dear programmers.

I have one problem, how I can use sessions in cakePHP?
When I use `$_SESSIONS["LOREM"]` and try to access some page error the sessions broken and destroy my layout, and sessions var disappear.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Read the docs: **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html**

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if your session get automatically destroyed, this sometime happens in cakephp in case of AUTH, due to some error page user gets relogin and Custom Session variables expires.

Try using Networks in Developer console by pressing F12 in Chrome and it will show you all stats and you can figure out if you are being relogin or not.

Also if it doesn't help pls provide some code. also read error logs stacks.